# What is the best way to send progress information from WCF to the browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, html

I have an MVC application using Razor, html5 and a WCF service. The problem is one WCF service takes a long time to run which means that the user has no indication what the service is doing. I would like to send progress information to the HTML5 client and would like some suggestions over what the best approach would be. All help will be gratefully received…

Comment: You want to send real progress information (like `7.4% complete`) coz that's gonna be a real challenge or just an animated gif that spins around during the operation telling the user that his request is being processed at the moment?

Comment: Some text information would be sufficient for the application that I am currently working on. But I have some up-coming projects that might need percentage completed information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even use SignalR for the Reverse Ajax purpose. If you want to shy away from these heavy framework, and probably want to go with setInterval you can check out this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580729.aspx) This article is by Dino Espito, in which talks about how to use setInterval to make repetitive call to server to get the progress. [Another one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx) by Dino Espito in which he uses SignalR libarary to make a context sensitive progress bar

For Full Collection of his article on Context Sensitive Progress Bar [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532098.aspx?sdmr=DinoEsposito&sdmi=authors)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go for [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) implementation. In the case of Comet or Reverse Ajax the client will send a long duration ajax call to the server and wait for a response. So in your case first the HTML5 client will send a request to the server and wait for the progress information once the WCF service returns some info back the client has to make the again make the long duration call till the process is completed.

There are open-sources available that helps to simplify your work like [nComet](http://ncomet.codeplex.com/) or [PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com/releases/view/51900).

There is also an article available in [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186723/Push-Messages-in-RESTful-WCF-Web-Application-with) that talks about this approach.